# Flutter "context " Navigatior.pushedNamed generator RouteSettings

Tags: flutter, routes, navigator

my `Navigator.pushNamed` does not work anymore since I refactored my BottomNavigationBar into a new class. The `setState()` works fine, so I strongly assume that there is a problem with the `context`. The BottomNavigationBar shows up in the app but it won't route me to the next page anymore. I am struggling for hours now to figure this out...

The error I get is:
**Could not find a generator for route RouteSettings("...", null) in the _WidgetsAppState.**

The **NewBottomNavigationBar** class

```
class NewBottomNavigationBar extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NewBottomNavigationBarState createState() => _NewBottomNavigationBarState();
}

class _NewBottomNavigationBarState extends State<NewBottomNavigationBar> {
  int _selectedTab = 0;
  final _selectedTabList = [
    TheSlateScreen.id,
    Search.id,
    LoginScreen.id,
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

return BottomNavigationBar(
    currentIndex: _selectedTab,
    onTap: (int index) {
      setState(() {
        _selectedTab = index;
      });

      Navigator.pushNamed(
        context,
        _selectedTabList[_selectedTab].toString(),
      );
    },
    unselectedItemColor: kSlate,
    items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
```

......

**The class where I use the NewBottomNavigation()**

```
class TheSlateScreen extends StatefulWidget {
      static const String id = 'theslate_screen';
      @override
      _TheSlateScreenState createState() => _TheSlateScreenState();
    }
    
    class _TheSlateScreenState extends State<TheSlateScreen> {   



 @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
        screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

return MaterialApp(
 home: Scaffold(
    bottomNavigationBar: NewBottomNavigationBar(),
    appBar: AppBar(
      leading: null,
      actions: <Widget>[
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.close),
```

.....

**The routes in my main.dart**

```
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
        create: (context) => SlateTasks(),
        child: MaterialApp(
          initialRoute: LoginScreen.id,
          routes: {
            LoginScreen.id: (context) => LoginScreen(),
            RegistrationScreen.id: (context) => RegistrationScreen(),
            TheSlateScreen.id: (context) => TheSlateScreen(),
            ResetPasswordScreen.id: (context) => ResetPasswordScreen(),
            Search.id: (context) => Search(),
          },
        ));
```

Comment: Does this answer your question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49132299/could-not-find-a-generator-for-route/49132388

Comment: it acutally works to replace the "return MaterialApp" with "return Scaffold". I don't understand why though. The code worked perfectly fine before with 2 "return MaterialApp". I don't get why the refactoring messed this up

Comment: You should use only one `MaterialApp` as the root of your widget tree.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not find a generator for route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49132299/could-not-find-a-generator-for-route)