# flutter: Could not find a generator for route RouteSettings(“/HairServices-product-detail”, 1) in the I/flutter (26461): _WidgetsAppState

Tags: flutter

i have created categories with tab bars inside a page called shop all in flutter , when i visit those categories it works fine but when i tap on product to view it's details it show me the error i mentiod above in question , is there a way to fix it?

ps: i added all routes in main.dart and still same problem

```html
   

class HairServicesPdtItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final String imag;
  final double price;

  const HairServicesPdtItem({Key key, this.title, this.imag, this.price})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final pdt = Provider.of<Product>(context);
    final cart = Provider.of<Cart>(context);
    final wish = Provider.of<Wishe>(context);
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.of(context)
            .pushNamed(HairServicesDetailPage.routeName, arguments: pdt.id); //from here i called the detail page
        
            
      },
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5),
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                height: 140,
                width: 140,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                 image: AssetImage(imag),
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2),
                ),
                child: GridTile(
                  child: Image.asset(imag),
                  footer: GridTileBar(
                    leading: IconButton(
                      alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                      icon: Icon(
                        Icons.favorite,
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                          duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
                          content:
                              Text(' Item Successfully Added To Your Wishlist!'),
                                backgroundColor: HexColor("#D48C76"),
                        ));
                        wish.addItem(pdt.id, pdt.title, pdt.price, pdt.img);
                      },
                    ),
                    title: Text(''),
                    trailing: IconButton(
                      alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                      icon: Icon(
                        Icons.shopping_cart,
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                          duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
                          content:
                              Text(' Item Successfully Added To Your Cart!'),
                                 backgroundColor: HexColor("#D48C76"),
                        ));
                        cart.addItem(pdt.id, pdt.title, pdt.price, pdt.img);
                      },
                    ),
                    backgroundColor: Colors.white70,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 2),
              child: Text(
                title,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style:
                    TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
              ),
            ),
            Text("${price} AED",
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                )),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

routing :

```html
import 'package:./screens/HairServices_offers.dart';
import 'package:./screens/HairServices_pdt_detail.dart';

void main() => runApp(
    MaterialApp(debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false, home: Notification()));

class Notification extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [

        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: Products_HairServices()),

        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: Cart()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: Wishe()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
          value: Orders(),
        )
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          home: MyHomePage(),
          routes: {
          
            CartScreen.routeName: (ctx) => CartScreen(),
            WishList.routeName: (ctx) => WishList(),
       
            HairServicesDetailPage.routeName: (ctx) => HairServicesDetailPage(),
    
            
            HairServicesOffers.routeName: (ctx) => HairServicesOffers(),
      
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, could you post the code from your router generator? I'm sure it could be either (1) a small typo somewhere in  your router config or (2) you haven't created the configuration for that page in  your router config

Comment: i edited code and u please take a look cuz i spent two days and it didn't work

Comment: This could help https://stackoverflow.com/a/49132388/6322723

Comment: I tried this but didn't work too

Comment: i have posted an answer. try it out and get back to me if it works

Answer (score 0):

The problem is actually in the main file. You have 2 `MaterialApp()` widgets in your main file, which should not be the case.

Try to remove one of the `MaterialApp()` widgets like so:

```
import 'package:./screens/HairServices_offers.dart';
import 'package:./screens/HairServices_pdt_detail.dart';

void main() => runApp(Notification()); // I removed the MaterialApp() widget that was here.

class Notification extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [

        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: Products_HairServices()),

        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: Cart()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: Wishe()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
          value: Orders(),
        )
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          home: MyHomePage(),
          routes: {
      
            CartScreen.routeName: (ctx) => CartScreen(),
           WishList.routeName: (ctx) => WishList(),
   
            HairServicesDetailPage.routeName: (ctx) => HairServicesDetailPage(),

        
            HairServicesOffers.routeName: (ctx) => HairServicesOffers(),
  
          }),
    );
  }
}
```