# Could not find a generator for route RouteSettings("/coursePage", {img: img3, title: Numbers}) in the _WidgetsAppState

Tags: flutter, dart

a Flutter beginner here and I could use some of your help. I'm writing a "self-learning" app, and I want it to change screens when tapped on an icon or title.

This is what navigator I used:

`void openCoursePage(String img, String title) { Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/coursePage', arguments: {'img':'$img', 'title':'$title'}); }`

this is my onTap:

```
onTap: (){openCoursePage('$img', '$title');},
```

and route aswell:

```
routes: {
    '/coursePage' : (context)=>CoursePage(),
  },
```

And this is the error I get :

```
Could not find a generator for route RouteSettings("/coursePage", {img: img3, title: Numbers}) in the _WidgetsAppState.
```

[First Screen:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAuZi.png)
[Second Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SA5HT.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49132299/could-not-find-a-generator-for-route

Comment: @fartem I've looked into that one, but since I'm a newbie in this area, I barely understood what was going on there

Comment: Can you add code of your screens to the question?

Comment: @fartem I edited and added two screenshots of it (I didn't know any other option)

Comment: Are you using `MaterialApp` in second screen?

Comment: @fartem I'm not, should I ?

Comment: No. Post full code of your screens.