# Why could not find a generator for route RouteSettings("/coursePage", null) in the _WidgetsAppState occur when I run my code

Tags: flutter

I am really new to flutter. When I run my code, I found out that the screen cannot change from one page to another. I think I have miss or type something wrong. An error has occured as below.

```
Could not find a generator for route RouteSettings("/coursePage", null) in the _WidgetsAppState.

Make sure your root app widget has provided a way to generate 
this route.
Generators for routes are searched for in the following order:
 1. For the "/" route, the "home" property, if non-null, is used.
 2. Otherwise, the "routes" table is used, if it has an entry for the route.
 3. Otherwise, onGenerateRoute is called. It should return a non-null value for any valid route not handled by "home" and "routes".
 4. Finally if all else fails onUnknownRoute is called.
Unfortunately, onUnknownRoute was not set.
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      _WidgetsAppState._onUnknownRoute.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/app.dart:1228:9)
#1      _WidgetsAppState._onUnknownRoute (package:flutter/src/widgets/app.dart:1243:6)
#2      NavigatorState._routeNamed (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:4170:37)
#3      NavigatorState.pushNamed (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:4212:20)
#4      Navigator.pushNamed (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:1735:34)
...
Handler: "onTap"
Recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer#e3c7c
  debugOwner: GestureDetector
  state: possible
  won arena
  finalPosition: Offset(205.7, 652.3)
  finalLocalPosition: Offset(122.2, 26.0)
  button: 1
  sent tap down
```

I think something is wrong here, but I don't really know how to solve it

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      routes: <String,WidgetBuilder>{
      },
      initialRoute: MyHomePage.routeName,
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String routeName = "/";
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add all `routes` in your app to `routes` in `Material App` Widget, so your code should be like:

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      routes: <String,WidgetBuilder>{
       '/': (context) => const MyHomePage(),
        // change the route name of your second page here, if there is one :)
       '/secondPage': (context) => const MySecondPage(),
      },
      initialRoute: MyHomePage.routeName,
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String routeName = "/";
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
```

Official tutorial of the Flutter team for this topic is in: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/named-routes . Check for more infomation

Comment: Sadly it still isn't able to work. Does that mean I need to use OnGenerateRoute or UnknownRoute?

Comment: This will surely fix your problem, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49132299/could-not-find-a-generator-for-route/49132388

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have created your course.dart file class,You can create a file named **route.dart** as shown below:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:project_name/coursePage.dart';
import 'package:project_name/SplashPageExample.dart';

var routesPages = <><String, WidgetBuilder>{
'/': (BuildContext context) => SplashPageExample(),
'/coursePage': (BuildContext context) => coursePage(),
}
```

**NB:**the **'/'** string is just an automatic route for the first page you would like the application to show when a a restart has been made you can also add the course page there if you like.

Then on your **main.dart** file implement it as shown below:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:project_name/routes.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(const OnlineCommunity());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final globalScaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "Online Community",
      key: globalScaffoldKey,
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch().copyWith(
            primary: const Color(0x002bb9ad),
            secondary: const Color(0x00727474)),
      ),
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: routesPages,
    );
  }
}
```

You might want to navigate to the **coursePage** using the **onTap:(){}** and **onPress:(){}** methods of the **ElevatedButton** and **InkWell** widgets hence the recommended widget for Navigation is the one shown below eg:

```
child:ElevatedButton(
onPressed:(){
Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pushNamed("/coursePage");
}
),
```

or

```
child:InkWell(
onTap:(){
Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pushNamed("/coursePage");
}
child:Card()
),
```

Just incase of anything just tag me on the comments below: