# Could not find a generator for route RouteSettings

Tags: android, flutter, dart, navigator, state-management

I am working on NamedRoute but after all the connections and doing It right , I am unable to figure out why this error is occurring .

I tried using Navigator.of(Context).push(MaterialPageRoute()) , its working but Its not workking when i am trying to use  Navigator.of(context)
.pushNamed(Product_detail.routeName, arguments: id)

```
main.dart

import 'package:app4/screens/product_detail.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:app4/screens/product_description.dart';
import 'package:app4/screens/products.dart';
import 'package:app4/models/product.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Colors.purple,
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.highContrastDark(background: Colors.black12),
        fontFamily: 'Lato',
      ),
      home: Hey(),// this is grid view widget just for defining the gird
      routes: {Product_detail.routeName: (context) => Product_detail()},
    );
  }
}


products.dart

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:app4/screens/product_detail.dart';

class Products extends StatelessWidget {
  String imageUrl;
  String title;
  String id;
  Products(this.imageUrl, this.id, this.title);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(14),
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.of(context)
              .pushNamed(Product_detail.routeName, arguments: id);
        },
        child: GridTile(
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle, boxShadow: []),
            child: Image(
              fit: BoxFit.fill,
              height: 60,
              image: NetworkImage(imageUrl),
            ),
          ),
          footer: GridTileBar(
            leading: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.favorite),
              onPressed: () {},
              color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.background,
            ),
            backgroundColor: Colors.black54,
            title: Text(
              title,
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
            trailing: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_bag),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


product_detail.dart

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:app4/models/product.dart';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Product_detail extends StatelessWidget {
  // const Product_detail({super.key});

  // String id;
  // Product_detail(this.id);

  static const routeName = '/productDetail';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String? ideal = ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments.toString();
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("$ideal")),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this help?https://stackoverflow.com/q/49132299/8144311

Comment: Nope I tried All their methods

Answer (score 0):

Try using Material Page Route. Solved mine by using the article above

https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/passing-data

Answer (score 0):

Yep, I also face with same error and I can't solve unit now. So I used `Navigator.push()` instead of `pushNamed()`.
But there is one way, if want to use `pushNamed()` by passing **argument**, using `onGenerateRoute` is more clear and readable. Here I will show sample.

1. Build route_generator file to defined route path.
2. Pass `RouteGenerator.route` method in `onGenerateRoute` parameter of `Material()` widget.
3. From `onTap()` method just call `Navigator.pushNamed()` method and pass `arg`.
4. In **product_detail.dart**, declare **id** variable and can use that variable.

**route_generator.dart**

```
const productDetailRoute = '/productDetailRoute';

class RouteGenerator {
  static Route<dynamic> route(RouteSettings settings) {
    final args = settings.arguments;

    switch (settings.name) {
      case productDetailRoute:
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) {
            return Product_detail(
                id: args as String);
          },
        );

      default:
        return _errorRoute();
    }
  }

  static Route _errorRoute() {
    return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Center(child: Text('Error Page')),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: const [
              Text('Page not found'),
              Text('404'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    },);
  }
}
```

**main.dart**

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
      onGenerateRoute: RouteGenerator.route,
    );
  }
```

**products.dart**

```
onTap: () {
             Navigator.pushNamed(
             context, productDetailRoute,
             arguments: id);
          },
```

**product_detail.dart**

```
class Product_detail extends StatelessWidget {

  String id;
  Product_detail(this.id);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("$id")),
    );
  }
}
```

Note: as another advice, using class name with **CamelCase** is standard way.